What are the best known asymptotic bounds on the size of the largest non-trivial subgroup of the symmetric group?
To rephrase, how big can $\frac{|H|}{n!}$ get when $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $S_n$?
A trivial upper bound is $\frac{1}{2}$ due to Lagrange's theorem. An obvious, lazy lower bound is $\frac{1}{n}$ since $S_{n-1}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. What better asymptotic bounds are known/can be shown?
Edit: As pointed out in the comments by Chris Leary, the alternating subgroup $A_n$ achieves $\frac{1}{2}$, which I somehow completely missed.

The alternating group $A_n$ of even permutations is an index $2$ subgroup of $S_n$. It actually achieves your upper bound of $1/2$. You must decide if there is a nontrivial subgroup of greater cardinality than $n!/2$.

Since the alternating subgroup trivializes this question for $S_n$ we can re-ask the question for $A_n$. We always have a subgroup $A_{n-1}$ of index $n$ (for $n \ge 3$). If $G$ is a subgroup of index $d$, then $A_n$ acts transitively on the cosets $A_n/G$ and hence admits a nontrivial homomorphism
$$A_n \to \text{Aut}(A_n/G) \cong S_d$$
which for $n \ge 5$ must be injective since $A_n$ is simple. It follows that $d \ge n$. So it is not possible to do better than index $n$ for $n \ge 5$.
